# rails 3 flash message not displayed on mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mobile

My app enables images uploading.
The user , if successful , receives a success message:

the controller:

```
def create
    @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @rating.save
        format.html { redirect_to @rating, :notice => 'Got It!',
                                  :flash => {:notice_small => 'Your photo has been uploaded. good luck with its coolness rating!'} }
        format.json { render :json => @rating, :status => :created, :location => @rating }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @rating.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

the view:

```
<br>
<br>
<div style="height: 100px;" class="visible-tablet visible-phone"></div>
<p id="notice" class="big_notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% if defined? flash[:notice_small]  %>
    <p id="small_notice" class="small_notice"><%= flash[:notice_small] %></p>
<% end %>
```

which works fine on desktop. but not on mobile :-(
the pictures are uploaded but i just don't get the confirmation message

Edit: 
I viewed the source on mobile and displays the html like so

```
<p id="notice" class="big_notice"></p>
<p id="small_notice" class="small_notice"></p>
```

meaning that the `flash[:notice_small]` is defined(notice the `if defined? flash[:notice_small]` condition)  but it's just empty

Comment: Interesting.  Check this might help https://dev.tscolari.me/2011/09/15/how-to-build-a-mobile-rails-3-dot-1-app/

Comment: I doubt if this is a design issue.. it appears that rails doesnt support flash messages for mobile on the server side. it's a real brainer.. does anyone else has any suggetions?